# Key with multiple values - check if value is in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has a list of multiple values stored for each key. I want to check if a given value is in the dictionary, but this doesn't work:

```
if 'the' in d.values():
    print "value in dictionary"
```

Why doesn't it work with multiple values stored as a list? Is there any other way to test if the value is in the dictionary?

Comment: `if any('the' in value for value in d.values()):`? But if you need to go searching through all of the value lists, you may not have the best data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values is a list!

```
for item in d.values():
    if 'the' in item:
        print "value in dictionary"
```

Answer (score 4):

`d.values()` usually stores the values in list format. So you need to iterate through the list contents and check for the substring `the` is present or not.

```
>>> d = {'f':['the', 'foo']}
>>> for i in d.values():
        if 'the' in i:
            print("value in dictionary")
            break


value in dictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty simple:

```
>>> d = { 'a': ['spam', 'eggs'], 'b': ['foo', 'bar'] }
>>> 'eggs' in d.get('a')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the dictionary.
If your dictionary looks like follows:

```
my_dictionary = { 'names': ['john', 'doe', 'jane'], 'salaries': [100, 200, 300] }
```

Then you could do the following:

```
for key in my_dictionary:
    for value in my_dictionary[key]:
        print value
```

You can naturally search instead of print. Like this:

```
for key in my_dictionary:
    for value in my_dictionary[key]:
        if "keyword" in value:
            print "found it!"
```

There is probably a shorter way to do this, but this should work too.

Comment: Indentation needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether a value is there or not without any need to know the key it belongs to and all, you can go with this:

```
if 'the' in str(d.values())
```

Or for a one-liner, you can use the filter function

```
if filter(lambda x: 'eggs' in x, d.values()) # To just check
filter(lambda x: 'eggs' in d[x] and x, d) # To get all the keys with the value
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to write

```
if 0 < len([1 for k in d if 'the' in d[k]]):
    # do stuff
```

or equivalently

```
if 0 < len([1 for _,v in d.iteritems() if 'the' in v]):
    # do stuff
```